# Laptop is sluggish after docking

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance

I've got an MSI WS75 10TM-492 running Windows 10 enterprise.  I usually use it on a docking station (CalDigit TS3) and it runs great.  However, I'll occasionally take it off the docking station and after I put it back on its docking station it starts to be sluggish.  The sluggishness is most noticeable with typing.  I can sometimes type a whole word before it shows up on the screen (regardless of program).  Actual "number crunching" doesn't seem to be effected (for instance, running processor intensive scripts in `R`).  If I reboot the computer on the dock then after the reboot it'll be fine.  Of course, that's annoying to have to reboot my computer every time I take it off and put it back on the docking station.

Is there anything to be done to improve the post-docked performance?

Comment: What is the power mode when in this particular performance state?

Comment: @Ramhound not sure what that means...the "Power Options" was on Balanced but I just changed it to ultimate, which didn't seem to make a difference.  Is that what you meant or something else?

Comment: is it a wireless keyboard?

Comment: @Yorik, wired keyboard, wired mouse, 2 monitors.

Comment: This sounds like an interface handshaking loop of some sort. I understand some laptop manufacturers struggled with thunderbolt reset loops e.g. Lenovos had an issue if the laptop wasn't on its own charger before docking: people who poked into it saw 5 second hard resets on a loop without any expected handshaking. It is probably chipset and driver specific